# Is there a way to see achievements for the current mission?

Tags: starcraft-2

Whenever I finish a campaign mission I see the achievements for that mission in the summary screen, but that's an inconvenient place to see them (as you just finished playing it) -- If I achieved one it was most likely by chance.

I only found the Achievements screen accessible with the F9 key, but those are not grouped by mission, but for "group of missions".

Is there someplace I'm not finding to see achievements in the current mission? Or even before starting it?
This would be useful to try to get them the first time I play a mission.

Comment: I guess you meant to add "other than alt-tabbing and searching online".

Comment: Well, the thing about the F9 achievement screen is that it *should* open up the "group of missions" that includes the mission you're currently on, and additionally separates achieved from unachieved. Scroll down and you should find all achievements for that mission in a row (assuming you haven't completed any before).

Comment: @Raven Dreamer your comment should be the answer, IMO. The F9 achievement viewer is the only way to see the current mission's achievements. It's annoying that the current mission isn't highlighted, but it does pause the game, so you do have time to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reposted from comments, as suggested above:

> Well, the thing about the F9
>   achievement screen is that it should
>   open up the "group of missions" that
>   includes the mission you're currently
>   on, and additionally separates
>   achieved from unachieved. Scroll down
>   and you should find all achievements
>   for that mission in a row (assuming
>   you haven't completed any before).

What I liked to do (when I was completing SC2 achievements) was view the achievements *before* the mission, when you're on the Hyperion, so that I would know what to strive for immediately, going in.

Answer (score 1):

After you complete the mission and it is available in the mission replay screen, the achievements and completion time for each difficult level is displayed for each mission

Comment: Down vote explanation please?